# Laravel relationship with multiple foreign keys

Tags: php, database-design, laravel, laravel-4

What is the standard way to set up your tables and models with table that have multiple foreign keys.

Example one foreign key relationships typicall look like

```
database tables:

clients
    id
    name
doctors
    id
    name
client_doctor
    client_id
    doctor_id
```

But for my example, a doctor also may be associated with multiple clinics, and at each clinic may have multiple types.

I want to refactor my tables to reflect laravel standards but currently my tables look like

```
clients
doctors
clinics
doctypes
doctor_clinic_doctype
    doctor_id
    clinic_id
    doctype_id
client_doctor_clinic_type
    client_id
    the three columns from doctor_clinic_type as a foreign key
```

What is best practice here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Eloquent will give pivot tables also an id column you could match on that id.

So the tables might look like this.

```
doctor_clinic_doctype
    id
    doctor_id
    clinic_id
    doctype_id

client_doctor_clinic_type
    client_id
    doctor_clinic_doctype_id (foreign key on doctor_clinic_doctype.id)
```

I think this is probably the only solution that will work well with Eloquent (not sure though).